# type or namespace could be found - even though i declared the variable

Tags: c#, .net

i am getting this error:

> The type or namespace name 'myObject' could not be found

on this line:

```
if (typeof(myObject) != typeof(String))
```

here is the surrounding code:

```
 for (int rCnt = 1; rCnt <= EmailList.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
            {
                object myObject = (EmailList.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                if (typeof(myObject) != typeof(String))
                    continue;
                cell = (string)(EmailList.Cells[ rCnt,1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
                if (cell!=null)
                    emails.Add(cell.ToString());
            }
```

what am i doing wrong? i'm obviously declaring myObject. thanks so much for your guidance.

Answer (score 7):

The [`typeof` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) takes a type identifier, not an instance identifier, as the argument.

You want `myObject.GetType()` to get the type of an object:

```
if (myObject.GetType() != typeof(String))
```

Or even use the `is` operator instead:

```
if (!(myObject is String))
```

Comment: True - although you can ditch the null check if you use `is` instead

Answer (score 3):

`typeof` only works on a type name.

You want:

```
if (myObject.GetType() != typeof(String))
```

You can also use the `is` operator:

```
if (!(myObject is String))
```

The difference only shows up when you are dealing with inheritance.

```
DerivedInstance.GetType() == typeof(BaseType) // false
DerivedInstance is BaseType // true
```

As mentioned in comments, `null` is an issue. If `DerivedInstance` is actually null:

```
DerivedInstance.GetType() == typeof(BaseType) // NullReferenceException
DerivedInstance is BaseType // false
```

Answer (score 2):

you need myObject.GetType() or you can use

```
if ((myObject as string)==null)
```

Answer (score 2):

as BoltClock's a Unicorn mentioned, in this case you need `GetType()`. In addition, the whole code you wrote is unnecessary.

```
            object myObject = (EmailList.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2;
            if (typeof(myObject) != typeof(String)) // !(myObject is String) is enough. Plus, this won't work, if myObject is null.
                continue;
            cell = (string)(EmailList.Cells[ rCnt,1] as Excel.Range).Value2; // you can operate with myObject here as well
            if (cell!=null) // in case of object having type, this is unnecessary.
                emails.Add(cell.ToString()); // why calling ToString() on string?
```

the only thing you need is

```
string str = (EmailList.Cells[rCnt, 1] as Excel.Range).Value2 as string;
if (str != null)
    emails.add(str);
```

Comment: wouldnt your first line return an exception since you cannot assign a non strnig value to a string

Comment: no, I'm casting (`as string`). The `as` operator returns casted value OR `null` in case the cast cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

typeof is for **types** and not for **instances**, change it to

```
myObject.GetType()
```

Here are different solutions:

```
if (myObject.GetType() != typeof(String))

if (!(myObject is String))

if ((myObject as String)==null)
```

Answer (score 0):

typeof takes a type as an argument. You've passed it an object instead. What you are probably trying to do is:

```
if (myObject.GetType() != typeof(string))
```